# How to track if uninstall of package succeeded

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, uninstallation

I have some launcher app and I offer a direct uninstall app function. I do it like following:

```
public static void uninstallApp(String packageName)
{
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName);
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    uninstallIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (uninstallIntent != null)
        MainApp.get().startActivity(uninstallIntent);
}
```

The problem is, the user could select cancel, so I can't remove the app from my launcher before I get the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` intent in my broadcast receiver. Unfortunately this mostly needs some seconds and for a launcher this is somehow disappointing as a user expects the item to vanish immediately after they uninstall it through my launcher.

Is there a better (faster) way to do that? Can I somehow listen to the result of my uninstall call?

Comment: "Unfortunately this mostly needs some seconds and for a launcher this is somehow disappointing as a user expects the item to vanish immediately after they uninstall it through my launcher" -- one option is to optimistically assume that the user doesn't cancel the install and just hide all launcher icons for that app. If, after some time T, you do not receive `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`, you show those launcher icons again. Optionally, during that time T, check `PackageManager` periodically to see if the activities are available, in case it gets updated before the broadcast goes out.

Comment: I am doing it like that currently. Still this is somehow confusing if the user cancels the uninstall and suddenly does not see the app in the launcher anymore... thanks for the idea though... I currently assume that the uninstall was cancelled if the broadcast is not received within 15s... considering this I'm not sure if the delay before removing the app from the launcher is the better way from the point of user experience... if there is no solid and better solution

Comment: I'm not aware of anything better. `ACTION_DELETE` is not documented to return anything, in terms of `startActivityForResult()`. `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` *is* documented to return a status, though the docs feel like a copy-and-paste job from `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`, and I don't know if it really works. Also, that would only be an option for API Level 14+; for older devices, if you support them, you might have to stick with your current approach.

Comment: I do only support devices above. But I use a service without an activity so I would have to create a dummy activity to catch the result of that alternative action... thanks for the ideas